# How to remove Extra indent in XML Dom in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am writing a method in the java where it writes appends data to the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Esko>

    <Employees>
                      
    </Employees>

</Esko>
```

Here I want to append employee data to this employees tag something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<MyOrg>
 

<Employees>
                              

    <Employee>
        <Name>gaurav kumar </Name>
        <Designation>SSSSS</Designation>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Name>gaurav kumar </Name>
        <Designation>SSSSS</Designation>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Name>gaurav</Name>
        <Designation>singh</Designation>
    </Employee>
</Employees>

</MyOrg>
```

For that I am using this Code:

```
public void saveToXML(String xml) {
    Document dom;
    NodeList employees = null;
    Node eRoot = null;
    // instance of a DocumentBuilderFactory
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        // use factory to get an instance of document builder
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        // create instance of DOM
        dom = db.parse(xml);
     
        // create the root element
      //  Element rootEle = dom.getElementByName("Esko");
      
        // create data elements and place them under root
        employees = dom.getElementsByTagName("Employees");
        System.out.println(employees.item(0));
        eRoot = employees.item(0);

        
        eRoot.appendChild(createEmployee(dom, nameField.getText(), designationField.getText()));
        
        

        try {

            Transformer tr = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            tr.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

            
            // send DOM to file
            tr.transform(new DOMSource(dom), 
                                 new StreamResult(new FileWriter(xml)));

        } catch (TransformerException te) {
            System.out.println(te.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        System.out.println("UsersXML: Error trying to instantiate DocumentBuilder " + pce);
    } catch (SAXException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Element createEmployee(Document dom, String name, String des)
{
    Element e = dom.createElement("Employee");
    Element eName = dom.createElement("Name");
    Element eDes = dom.createElement("Designation");
    
    //create name and designation as child tag of Employee tag
    e.appendChild(eName);
    e.appendChild(eDes);
    
    // name tag contain what is supplied by the user at name field
    eName.appendChild(dom.createTextNode(name));
    // designation tag contains the designation by the user
    eDes.appendChild(dom.createTextNode(des));
    return e;
}
```

But now what is happening is that every time I am saving a new employee it adding extra indentation to the XML like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<MyOrg>
        

<Employees>
                
    
    <Employee>
                    
        <Name>gaurav</Name>
                    
        <Designation>SDET</Designation>
                
    </Employee>
        
    <Employee>
        <Name>gaurav kumar</Name>
        <Designation>SDET2</Designation>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
    

</MyOrg>
```

I am not sure of the reason for it but it is happening because I am setting indentation every time it saves to xml. Can anyone help me why it is happening and how can I save it without these extra indentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespaces can be removed from XML document using following helper function:

```
 public static void removeWhitespaces(Element element) {
    NodeList children = element.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = children.getLength() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Node child = children.item(i);
        if (child instanceof Text
            && ((Text) child).getData().trim().isEmpty()) {
            element.removeChild(child);
        } else if (child instanceof Element) {
            removeWhitespaces((Element) child);
        }
    }
}
```

It can be called `removeWhitespaces(dom.getDocumentElement());` before calling `tr.transform()`.